# django DetailView doesn't catch data from ManyToMany field

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-orm

I have 3 models: first main "Stones" connect by ForeignKey with "Typs" and Many-to-Many with "Mentions".
When I try to write a template for detail view for each "stone" with DetailView class, it shows data only from "Stones" and "Typs", not from 'Mentions"

my models.py (necessary part)

```
class StonesManager(models.Manager):
def all_with_prefetch_mentions(self):
    qs = self.get_queryset()
    return qs.prefetch_related('mentions')


class Stones(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Назва')
place = models.TextField(verbose_name='Месцазнаходжанне')
legend = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Легенда')
typ = models.ForeignKey('Typ', null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Тып')
objects = StonesManager()

class Typ(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=20, db_index=True, verbose_name='Назва тыпу')
def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class StonesImage(models.Model):
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=stones_directory_path_with_uuid)
uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
stones = models.ForeignKey('Stones', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Mentions(models.Model):
work = models.TextField(verbose_name='Праца')
year = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
sacral_objects = models.ManyToManyField(Stones, related_name='mentions', verbose_name='Сакральны аб\'ект')
```

my views.py (necessary part)

```
class StonesDetail(generic.DetailView):
queryset = Stones.objects.all_with_prefetch_mentions()
template_name = 'volumbf/stone_detail.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['image_form'] = self.stones_image_form()
    return context

def stones_image_form(self):
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
        return StonesImageForm()
    return None
```

my template (necessary part)
1. All are shown in the right way

```
<h2> {{ stones.title}} </h2>
<p>{{ stones.legend }} </p>
<p>{{ stones.place }}</p>
<p>Typ: <a href="/volumbf/{{ stones.typ.pk }}/">{{ stones.typ.name }}</a></p>
```

2. Isn't shown at all

Mentions:

```
{% for work in stones.mentions.work %}
        <p><a href="{% url 'work_detail' work.pk %}"> {{ stones.mentions.work }}</a></p>
{% endfor %}


 {% for i in object.stonesimage_set.all %}
        <li class="list-inline-item" >
            <img scr="{{ i.image.url }}">
        </li>
 {% endfor %}

{% if image_form %}
    <div>
        <h2 >Upload New Image</h2>
    <form method="post"
          enctype="multipart/form-data"
          action="{% url 'StonesImageUpload' stones_id=object_id %}" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ image_form.as_p }}
        <p ><button class="btn btn-primary"></button> </p>
    </form>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

I suppose "stones.mentions.work" isn't the right name, but I'm not sure. Please, I do my first steps here and need any help.

Answer (score 1):

I was right, the mistake was in the template, see below

```
{% for work in stones.mentions.all %}
    <p><a href="{% url 'work_detail' work.pk %}"> {{ work }}</a></p>
{% endfor %}

{% for i in object.stonesimage_set.all %}
        <li class="list-inline-item" >
            <img src="{{ i.image.url }}" alt="{{ i.id }}" >
        </li>
{% endfor %}

action="{% url 'StonesImageUpload' stones.pk %}"
```

Comment: could I ask you one more question about the same topic? I don't know how to write in private here

Answer (score 0):

My solution worked with Django 3

### using DetailView and ModelForm

models.py

```
class DispCause(models.Model):
reason = models.CharField(
    max_length = 100,
    default = 'Late Delivery'
)

class Dispute(models.Model):
   dispcause = models.ManyToManyField(DispCause,
        related_name='disputes')
    msg = models.TextField(
        max_length=2000
      )
```

---

forms.py

```
class DisputeForm(forms.ModelForm):
dispcause = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    label = "Select reason(s) for your complain",
    queryset = DispCause.objects.all(),
    widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
```

---

views.py

```
class DisputeDetails(DetailView):
model = Dispute
template_name = TEMPLATE_DIR + "details.html"
```

---

template

```
  {% for w in object.dispcause.all %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ w }}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```